# Update a remote stock database

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce

I am building an online store with craft commerce, but I have a problem, I need to update a remote stock on every purchase, this stock is located in a remote server, do you know if  exist a plugin that makes this task easier for me?

Maybe a plugin that sends a POST API on every purchase or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a first party web hooks plugin available here:

https://plugins.craftcms.com/webhooks
https://github.com/craftcms/webhooks

That may well do what you need, but I have no personal experience of it, and of course any pre-built plugin will have some limitations.

Alternatively, you can write your own module to do this of course (https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/module-guide.html)

In essence, in that, you would listen to Commerce events (see https://craftcms.com/docs/commerce/3.x/extend/events.html for information on those) - and take whatever action you like when the event is triggered.  Of course you have the full power/scope of PHP to do anything you like at that point.

It's highly likely you'll end up needing at least some custom module code in a typical Commerce project, so this might be a good place to get started!

Comment: it's just what I was looking for. Thank you!